# Como redirigir a otro servidor en PHP

Tags: php, php5

Estoy utilizando un servicio en PHP a modo de pasarela de pagos tipo Redsys en la que se conecta, realiza el pago con tarjeta y obtiene un código de respuesta.

Esta respuesta necesito redirigirla a otro servidor externo con el código de pedido para notificar la respuesta dada por este servicio.

La respuesta debe ser enviada por método POST pero no sé como hacerlo ya que no estoy usando ningún formulario, simplemente recibo los datos por POST y ese mismo POST quiero redirigirlo a otro servidor externo.

Saludos.

Comment: Te recomiendo poner el código de ejemplo para se mas especifico al realizar tu pegunta

Comment: Puedes hacerlo mediante un curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se me ocurren tres formas:

```
* Curl
* Generas un form dinámico
* Petición AJAX
```

En modo curl sería:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://domain.ltd/';
    $fields = array(
        'variable' => urlencode($_POST['valor'])
    );
    foreach($fields as $key => $value) {
        $fields_string .= $key .'=' . $value . '&';
    }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Generar un form dinámico (Aquí yo lo haría con jQuery):

```
    $('<form action="http://domain.ltd/"><input type="text" name="variable" value="valor"></form>').appendTo('body').submit();
```

En petición AJAX (jQuery nuevamente):

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://domain.ltd",
    data: {
        variable: "valor"
    }
});
```

Puede que haya más formas, pero esto es lo básico.

Comment: No puedo generar un formulario y enviarlo por ajax ya que necesito mostrar la web del servidor que se conecta a ese servicio, este servicio simplemente hace de intermediario para codificar y decodificar los datos y vuelve a redirigir al servidor. simplemente necesito saber si hay alguna manera de hacer una llamada HTTP a una url con unos datos en POST

Comment: Yo creo que lo he explicado, puedes usar el primer método con Curl

Comment: Lo probraré, muchas gracias.